# Efficient way of computing `np.diagonal(np.dot(A, B), axis1=1, axis2=2)` using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `A` of shape `(n, m, k)` and `B` of shape `(k, m)`. I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to perform the following operation:

> `np.diagonal(np.dot(A, B), axis1=1, axis2=2)`

since it's performing a lot of computations I don't need in the `np.dot` (I only need the diagonals along 2 axis of the resulting `3-D` array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
np.einsum('ijk,kj->ij', A, B)
```

Another option is

```
(A * B.T).sum(axis=-1)
```

but in a few tests of arrays of various sizes, the `einsum` version was consistently faster.

Comment: `(A[:,:,None,:]@B.T[None,:,:,None]).squeeze()` may be faster, but it's harder to explain.